# bootstrap 4.3.1 tab not working in my project

Tags: bootstrap-4

I almost copied the code from their website. The tab is initiated perfectly, and when I click on tabs, new panels are activated. However, the "active" class is not applied to the activated tab. This is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="messages-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

my js

```
$('#myTab a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Remove your javascript code, you don't need it. You use `data attributes` OR `JavaScript`, not both.

Comment: I removed it but it is not working

Comment: Add a code snippet with the complete code so we can test it.

Comment: When you click on the tab, can you inspect the code and check the applied style to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just **added CSS and JavaScript links** of Bootstrap in your code and it works perfectly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="messages-tab">...3</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">...4</div>
</div>
```